# jq: produce table containing parent and associated children elements

Tags: bash, jq

I have json like this

```
{
    "NetworkAcls": [
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "NetworkAclAssociationId": "aclassoc-0360bceb2b4788870",
                    "NetworkAclId": "acl-09811190de1965cd4",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-9fa0aac4"
                },
                {
                    "NetworkAclAssociationId": "aclassoc-08ceb0c1375cb9729",
                    "NetworkAclId": "acl-09811190de1965cd4",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-db2de5bd"
                }
            ],
            "Entries": [
                {
                    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "Egress": true,
                    "PortRange": {
                        "From": 80,
                        "To": 80
                    },
                    "Protocol": "6",
                    "RuleAction": "allow",
                    "RuleNumber": 100
                },
                {
                    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "Egress": true,
                    "PortRange": {
                        "From": 443,
                        "To": 443
                    },
                    "Protocol": "6",
                    "RuleAction": "allow",
                    "RuleNumber": 200
                }
            ],
            "IsDefault": false,
            "NetworkAclId": "acl-09811190de1965cd4",
            "VpcId": "vpc-12345678",
            "OwnerId": "1234567890"
        },
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "NetworkAclAssociationId": "aclassoc-0531b6837ee6948dc",
                    "NetworkAclId": "acl-0f1c265110106d23d",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-7f23eb19"
                },
                {
                    "NetworkAclAssociationId": "aclassoc-01314abbaca73ae21",
                    "NetworkAclId": "acl-0f1c265110106d23d",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-44bdb71f"
                }
            ],
            "Entries": [
                {
                    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "Egress": false,
                    "PortRange": {
                        "From": 80,
                        "To": 80
                    },
                    "Protocol": "6",
                    "RuleAction": "deny",
                    "RuleNumber": 100
                },
                {
                    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "Egress": true,
                    "PortRange": {
                        "From": 443,
                        "To": 443
                    },
                    "Protocol": "7",
                    "RuleAction": "deny",
                    "RuleNumber": 200
                }
            ],
            "IsDefault": false,
            "NetworkAclId": "acl-0f1c265110106d23d",
            "VpcId": "vpc-12345678",
            "OwnerId": "1234567890"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I need to produce a table like this

```
| NetworkAclId            | RuleNumber    | Egress    | Protocol  | PortRange.From    | PortRange.To  | CidrBlock | RuleAction  |
|-------------------------|---------------|-----------|-----------|-------------------|---------------|-----------|-------------|
| acl-09811190de1965cd4   | 100           | true      | 6         | 80                | 80            | 0.0.0.0/0 | allow       |
| acl-09811190de1965cd4   | 200           | true      | 6         | 443               | 443           | 0.0.0.0/0 | allow       |
| acl-0f1c265110106d23d   | 100           | false     | 6         | 80                | 80            | 0.0.0.0/0 | deny        |
| acl-0f1c265110106d23d   | 200           | true      | 7         | 443               | 443           | 0.0.0.0/0 | deny        |
```

The Entries.* should only correspond to the NetworkAclId of its parent.

The closest I got was this but it produces so much duplication that I have to kill it.

```
.[][] | "\(.Associations[].NetworkAclId) \(.Associations[].SubnetId) \(.Entries[] | .CidrBlock) \(.Entries[] | .Egress) \(.Entries[] | .PortRange.From) \(.Entries[] | .PortRange.To) \(.Entries[] | .Protocol) \(.Entries[] | .RuleAction) \(.Entries[] | .RuleNumber)"
```

Something I don't get about jq is why every new field I add seems to produce exponentially increasing results.

For example this produces 4 results as expected:

```
.[][] | "\(.Associations[].NetworkAclId)"
```

But this produces 42 instead of the expected 4.

```
.[][] | "\(.Associations[].NetworkAclId) \(.Entries[] | .RuleNumber)"
```

How do I get jq to keep the associations of children to parent without associating every possible permutation of values in the input?

Thank you

Comment: small bug in your json, line 80 ends with comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a formulation to output the data you want as CSV:

```sh
jq -r '
    .NetworkAcls[] | range(.Associations | length) as $i | [
        .Associations[$i].NetworkAclId,
        (.Entries[$i] |
            .RuleNumber,
            .Egress,
            .Protocol,
            .PortRange.From,
            .PortRange.To,
            .CidrBlock,
            .RuleAction
        )
    ] | @csv
' file.json
```

```
"acl-09811190de1965cd4",100,true,"6",80,80,"0.0.0.0/0","allow"
"acl-09811190de1965cd4",200,true,"6",443,443,"0.0.0.0/0","allow"
"acl-0f1c265110106d23d",100,false,"6",80,80,"0.0.0.0/0","deny"
"acl-0f1c265110106d23d",200,true,"7",443,443,"0.0.0.0/0","deny"
```

I figure it's easier to ask how to turn CSV into a table than JSON.

Comment: Great idea to use the range() function to generate an iterator. Thanks! 
In the end I used your answer with a little change: I found it worked by iterating over "range(.Entries | length) as $i" instead and take .NetworkAclId.

Comment: Thanks. It was a bit awkward that the Associations and Entries are "parallel" instead of bundled together. I was reading through the jq manual thinking "how do I iterate over the _indices_ of an array?"

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the following :

```
.NetworkAcls[] | [.Associations, .Entries] | combinations | \
"\(.[0].NetworkAclId) \(.[1].RuleNumber) \(.[1].Egress) \(.[1].Protocol) \(.[1].PortRange.From) \(.[1].PortRange.To) \(.[1].CidrBlock) \(.[1].RuleAction)"
```

[Try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/L2PUyy4J6J)

This returns 8 elements as there are two NetworkAcls elements with each two associations and two entries.

Comment: I like the use of combinations but I chose the answer from @glennjackman as it can cope with any number of objects in .NetworkAclId.